# Open source and closed source Titanium

Tags: open-source, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm building an application in Appcelerator studio. I'm using a third party module. I came across a problem using that module, I contacted the developer of module and he said you're using a closed source Titanium. If I try with open source Titanium I'll be good to go. So, my question is what is the difference between open source Titanium and close source Titanium.
I'm stuck in this problem please if someone can help, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be a good fit for SO, but let me answer your question what the difference is between open and closed source Titanium:

- The Titanium SDK is [open source](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile)
- The Titanium CLI is [open source](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium)
- The Appcelerator CLI and Studio are not

As for the error: modules should work regardless of whether you use the Titanium CLI or Appcelerator CLI/Studio to build. So I wonder what the maintainer could mean. What is the error?

Comment: Thank you so much my dear ... Error has been resolved, Error was related to calendar , now working fine on the real device but not on Emulator....